# How to add Push Notification for same app, which is transferred from other Apple Developer's account?

Tags: ios, push-notification

The case which I am facing is different than usual. I developed an app. I uploaded to AppStore a year ago.

Now I transferred the App from my previous account to current account and set status "Removed From Sale".

I made the app from scratch again. Now I want to add Push Notification for my new app.

When I click Registering an App ID, it says men that

**An App ID with Identifier 'com.mycompany.mynewapp' is not available. Please enter a different string.**

Now, I don't have existing certificate from this Identifier. How can I made Certificate of Same Identifier and continue developing app.

Kindly Help.

Its a bit complex. If anyone is not clear, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: App Identifier is unique for all app so for new app you have to create new identifier for new app

Comment: But this is not new app. I think you didn't through question at all. I transferred app from my previous account to new account. But in new account, I don't have App Identifier in my Developer portal. @Jaimish

Comment: I think you have no idea about transferring of app, so if you have, lets discuss else move on with your daily tasks.  This Question is for higher level. @Jaimish